# How do you automatically tab ALL the selected text when using a SurroundsWith SnippetType?

Tags: sql, visual-studio, code-snippets

Below is my SQL snippet that is used to surround existing SQL. After highlighting some SQL and inserting this snippet, I want **ALL** the selected text to be indented by a tab or several spaces. My snippet currently will indent just the first line of highlighted code.

How can I make is indent all the selected text?

Here is my SQL snippet.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CodeSnippets xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2005/CodeSnippet">
    <CodeSnippet Format="1.0.0">
        <Header>
            <Title>Insert a comment header for SQL</Title>
            <Shortcut>header</Shortcut>
            <Description>SQL Snippet will add comment area for header to break up code</Description>
            <Author>Mike Adams</Author>
            <SnippetTypes>
                <SnippetType>SurroundsWith</SnippetType>
                <SnippetType>Expansion</SnippetType>
            </SnippetTypes>
        </Header>
        <Snippet>
            <Declarations>
                <Literal Editable="true">
                    <ID>headerText</ID>
                    <ToolTip>Header Text</ToolTip>
                    <Default></Default>
                    <Function></Function>
                </Literal>
            </Declarations>
            <Code Language="sql">
                <![CDATA[
-- $headerText$
---------------------------------------------------------
     $selected$

$end$
]]>
            </Code>
        </Snippet>
    </CodeSnippet>
</CodeSnippets>
```